# How to run simultaneous live search filters in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have several blocks of HTML like the one below named **recordContainer** within the **records**  `<div>`, generated dynamically. To refer to the whole block when querying it I'm using:

`$(".records div.recordContainer").each(function(){`

```
  <div id="records">
        <div class="recordContainer" id="article0">
             <div class="lineDivide"></div>
             <span class="listLeadAuthor"> Brian May</span>

  <br /> 
             <span class="listSubject">Cheese</span>
            <br />
             <span class="listDate">2008</span>
       </div> 
</div>
```

**I'd like to refer to the individual span elements only** as I have three different search boxes.

Here's a JSFiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish. When I enter an author name in the recordContainer, I want to hide the whole other recordContainer that doesn't match, not just the author name. I want to be able only search the visible elements, rather than starting fresh on each search.

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zv5rY/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this with id:

```
div id="records">
```

but you are referring it with **class notation `'.'`** use `'#'` **For id notation** in jQuery.

```
$("#records div.recordContainer span.listLeadAuthor").each(function(){
//-^---this one
```

But i think this would perform better:

```
$("div.recordContainer span.listLeadAuthor").each(function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

ID's are # :

```
$("#records div.recordContainer span.listLeadAuthor")
```

Comment: I've updated the question with a JSFiddle with the context of how im trying to use it.